# Spring Method Security does not support permitAll

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using spring's global method security functionality to provision service methods. 
What I tried was to declare `@PreAuth("hasRole('ROLE_TEST')")` in class level and make some of the methods to be accessed by all using `@PreAuth("permitAll")`.

What I found was that,

1. spring does not override the `@PreAuth` defined on the class level by the `@PreAuth` defined in the method level.
2. spring method level security does not understand the expression `permitAll`.

Below mentioned are the configurations that I used.

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.yyy.zzz" />
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Service class.

```
@PreAuth("hasRole('ROLE_TEST')")
public Class Test {

    public void testMethodOne(){}

    @PreAuth("permitAll")
    public void testMethodTwo(){}
}
```

Can you please provide any point that I am missing ?

Comment: There is no `@PreAuth` annotation so I either assume you mean `@PreAuthorize` or have your own implementation which isn't processed by Spring Security. Does your class-level annotation even work? I would expect 1 and 2 to function correctly and that you simply have multiple instances of the service and you are using an unproxied one. Which Spring Security version are you using.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. My Bad its a type mistake. I'm using `@PreAuthorize`. Spring version is 3.2.4.RELEASE, Spring Security Version 3.2.4.RELEASE.

The class level annotation is working fine. But the issue is that the class level annotation is not getting overiden by the method level annotation. I have only one version of the implementation and even I modified the configuration to `<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">` however the behavior is the same.